# Select unique count using two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns of interest: `apc` and `tid`. The same `apc` can be in a row with multiple `tid`s, and an `apc` - `tid` pair can appear multiple times in the database (with different timestamps).

I want to get the `apc`s with a count of how many unique `tid`s they match with. So for:

```
apc        tid
---------------
abc        012
abc        012
abc        322
def        322
def        432
def        000
```

I want to get:

```
apc        count
-----------------
abc          2
def          3
```

I tried doing a group by on`apc` and `tid`, but I get all of the duplicates as unique counts (so 3 and 3 above). I tried throwing in distinct in a few places, but that didn't work either.

Comment: This is a basic aggregation query with `count(distinct)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `Count(Distinct tid)`:

```
Select  apc, Count(Distinct tid) as Count
From    Table
Group by apc
```